# how to change the element input button tobe A or Span

Tags: javascript, input, textarea

BEFORE CODE

```
$( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function(){
            var cursorPos = $('#spotsettings-template-code').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#spotsettings-template-code').val();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $('#spotsettings-template-code').val( textBefore+ $(this).val() +textAfter );
        });
```

AFTER CODE : example down here

```
$( 'a' ).on('click', function(){
        var cursorPos = $('#text').prop('selectionStart');
        var v = $('#text').val();
        var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
        var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
        $('#text').val( textBefore+ $(this).val() +textAfter );
    });
```

**But dont work ,,, its possible change input[type=button] to be  or**

```
<form>
    <textarea id="text" cols="40" rows="3"> </textarea>
<a>[tag_label]</a> or <span>[tag_label]</span>
</form>
```

Sorry for bad english! 
Regards
Regga

Comment: Same way a css selector would specify an or conditional.  `a, span`  Commas denote an OR, no space denotes an AND, and spacing without commas denote nesting.

Comment: However keep in mind, `a` and `span` tags **do not** have a value.  They have inner text or inner html

Comment: can you show me how i should do ?

Comment: `$(this).text()` would get the content of an `a` or `span` tag, rather than using `val()`

Comment: i have try for your suggestion but it not working , can u explain more what sould i changed the script? i need it so much

Comment: `$( 'a' )` changes to `$('a, span')`, and `$(this).val()` changes to `$(this).text()`.

Comment: the best sollution thanks so much it works for real 100% works . big thanks for this sollution dear taplar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer from tamplar

```
$('span').on('click', function(){
            var cursorPos = $('#text').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#text').text();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $('#text').val( textBefore+ $(this).text() +textAfter );
        });
```